# Saving Cookie with CURL on linux

Tags: cookies, curl

We use CURL to automate some administrative tasks on a web application that uses SSO cookie for all the sites on the domain. Recently, there was a change in the authentication system on the application that we had been automating with. That's fine. We changed the CURL script to conform to the new authentication. We are able to get cookies and save to the jar.

The problem is the way the cookie is saved. I looked at how the headers in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox and the response headers are the same that I see in CURL. However the cookie in the cookie jar isn't saving the cookie in a way that it can be sent to the subsites in the Domain.

The CURL Example is as follows:

> curl -c mycookie "https://login.example.com" -d loginUID=myusername -d loginPWD=mypassword

The format it's saving is:

> login.example.com   FALSE   /   TRUE   SSOCookie   automatedvalue

The cookie will be consumed by the subsites if we manually change the cookie to:

> .example.com   TRUE   /   TRUE   SSOCookie   automatedvalue

I'm not sure why the cookies would be saved as such.

Does anyone know what would cause CURL to save the cookies as such? Or if there is a work around other than manually/scripting a change to be used for the entire domain?

Note: When I do a -v on setting the cookies. It says *Replased cookie SSOCookie "uniquecookieid" for domain login.cat.com

Thank you,

Comment: Can you provide an example of the CURL you're using to set the cookie?

Comment: I went ahead and added an example. Here it is: 
curl -c mycookie "https://login.example.com" -d loginUID=myusername -d loginPWD=mypassword

Comment: Since it's *reading* the remote cookie in this case, there's not really much you can do about it; the problem lies with the cookie you're retrieving. Are you able to change the way cookies are generated on the site itself? if not, you're going to be stuck writing something to parse and correct the cookies once they're downloaded.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of doing. One thing I figured out is if I use --dump-header header, I can use -b to send the header as a cookie and that works. The problem is the sub site also sets a session cookie, and I can't save and use both cookies

Comment: Right, exactly. If you're doing this purely with curl, I think you're SOL. What about using the CLI version of php and writing the cookie into curl that way?

Answer (score 8):

After spending two weeks and many hours I finally found the solution. The reason the cookie wasn't being set was because the server checked to see where the request was being made from. In the curl command I added a --referer to the domain of the site.

> curl -c mycookie "https://login.example.com" -d "loginUID=myusername" -d "loginPWD=mypassword" --referer "https://login.example.com"

The cookie jar now contains a cookie that can be used to send to the server.

Comment: How would this work for subdomains like https://login-other.example.com? Or in your situation, could you pass https://example.com and it would work?